# android parse JSON object in volley

Tags: android, json, gson

How to parse object like this in android volley ? (or GSON ?)
it is always a key, value. Keys are of course unknown, and length variable. I need to put it in hash map or Arraylist of simple objects

{
    "9784": 0.1,
    "71707": 0.1,
    "116271": 0.1,
    "118908": 0.5,
    "119162": 0.1,
    "119163": 0.1,
    "119181": 0.1,
    "119182": 0.1,
    "119183": 0.1,
    "119184": 0.1
}

Comment: In the mentioned answer is explained how to parse JSON if you know what value names are coming. Issue here is that I am receiving always  "key" : value  and I do not know their both values, just that one is string, one double

Comment: How to parse the JSON is explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android what are you trying to do is use the object created from the JSON. Have you tried looking how Java handles reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GSON you can parse it into Map.

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<Map<String,Double>>(){}.getType();  
Map<String,Double> map= new Gson().fromJson(JSON_STRING, listType);
```